# Refer static images or fonts in stylesheet when developing extensions for Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension.
And I want to use `background-image` attribute for some of the elements that I define through CSS. But I am not sure how the `url()` should be given. I tried relative URL, but it tries to fetch the image relative to the site's domain! Not relative to the extension's source directory.

The stylesheet is included to my extension via the manifest file as follows:

```
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.myblahblahsite.com/"],
      "js": ["core.js"],
      "css":["styles.css"]
    }
  ],
  ...
```

Also, I like to do the same with custom fonts too using the `@font-face`

For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'abcCustom';
    src:  url("fonts/abcCustom.ttf") format('ttf');
}
```

This won't properly consider the font's path relative to the extension!

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it an absolute url for your extension, the best way to do this would be like this:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'abcCustom';
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/abcCustom.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

This is part of the [`i18n`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n.html#overview-predefined) api.

Comment: Awesome! :) BTW, we need to mention this font in the `web_accessible_resources` section of the manifest file too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about encoding your images and fonts as Base64.